# Hibernate cleans permanently all existing data before it reads them

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
 Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Fund> funds = new ArrayList();

    try {

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "FROM Fund";// name of class, not a column
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        funds = query.getResultList();
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        session.close();
        return funds;
    }
}
```

I call the above portion of code on already filled MySql database. It wipes all data and returns an empty list of funds. After the program terminates, the db is empty. No error, no exception occurs during the execution. What is wrong?

Comment: Line with rollback isn't executed either. I checked it.

Comment: I have just configured **PostgresSql**, so that it has the same database and adapted .cfg.hbm file respectively. Unfortunately the result is quite the same as with MySql, so this **must** be the matter of the above code.

Comment: It was line 
     <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
in my hibernate-lending.cfg.xml  that caused the db was dropped at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It was line 
     create
in my hibernate-lending.cfg.xml  that caused the db was dropped at the end.